# How access session variable for cart id when using Ajax? How setup properties?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

After 5.3 update of laravel devs can't access session variable in constructors. Question is - how to setup CartController with properties which are based on session cart Id?

Just for example:

```
class CartController extends Controller
{
    public $cartId;
    public $cartProducts;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->cartId= $this->getCartId();
    $this->cartProducts = $this->getCartProducts();
}

public function getCartProducts()
{
    return CartProduct::with('product')->where('id_cart', $this->getCartId())->get();
}

public function getCartId()
{
    $sessionCartId = Session::get('cartId');
    $cookieCartId = Cookie::get('cartId');

    if ($cookieCartId) {
        $cartId = $cookieCartId;
        Session::put('cartId', $cartId);
    } elseif ($sessionCartId) {
        $cartId = $sessionCartId;
        Cookie::queue('cartId', $cartId, 10080);
    } else {
        $cartId = $this->setNewCart();
    }

    return $cartId;
}
```

In this example when I call via ajax getCartProducts() to get list of products I need to call method getCartId() instead property  $this->cartId. It is not bad **but** when I call more complex actions like deleting and refreshing tables  method getCartId will be called multiple times causing multiple queries. Now if I could access property I could get cartId in one query.

So question is - how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `session` data inside `__construct` using a `middleware` closure:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        $this->cartId = $this->getCartId();
        $this->cartProducts = $this->getCartProducts();

        return $next($request);
    });
}
```

Comment: Well I have tested this solution and  it did not work. I have used this in my __constructor and created new Cart object then called print_r to see what variables  I have. Properties was empty. Of course when I called on new object method $this->getCartId() it returned variable.

Comment: Cannot really say much without seeing exactly what you tried. In my example if you had a new function ```public function view() { print_r($this->cardId); }``` it should display the cart id if that function is called via a route.

Comment: I've checked code again and now it works. Maybe i've missed something last time. Thanks for help :)!

Comment: Maybe You know also answer for this question - when I create new Cart instance in other class (like order) and call cart property  $this->cartId (as in code above)  I cannot access any of properties. Cart looks like empty without fired constructor. Why is that happening?  (some test code here: https://codeshare.io/5ogxvr )